# How can i use DataContext Class in .Net Framework 2.0?

Tags: .net, frameworks, datacontext

I want to use DataContext Class in my project. 
But i use .Net FrameWork 2.0. What can i do? 
 There is any option in .Net Framework 2.o to use instead of DataContext class ?

Comment: Please provide some more details. Why do you want to use .NET 2.0? What is scenario you want to use the `DataContext` in? See also: [How to ask a question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean using Linq to SQL on .NET 2.0.

Linq2SQL requires .NET 3.5, however as far as I remember .NET 2.0 platform has not been changed for .NET 3.5, which means .NET 2.0 application can load .NET 3.5 assemblies. So in theory if you will have all required binaries in your output folder, you can use LINQ2SQL in your .NET 2.0 project.

Check out [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/08/27/Building-and-using-a-LINQ-for-SQL-Class-Library-with-ASP.NET-2.0.aspx).

Hope it helps.